# how to change the drawstring position when the user changes the coordinates values

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

i am planning to write something on a picture box.in the page load event i am able to do that.

```
 Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);
        Font font = new Font("Courier New", 6);      

        payagainst = "PARADISE TRADING, CONT &  REAL ESTATE";

        g.DrawString(payagainst, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), pagainstX, pagainstY);
```

My requirement is there is two textbox in the form ie to mention the the X and Y coordinates of the newly drawn label. If the user changes the values in the textbox position of the label has to be changed  according to the values given in the text box. in the text box leave event i have written the code as follows. but its not working. whats the correct method to achieve this.

```
private void txtpaX_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (flag != 0)
        {
            Graphics gs = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);
            Font font = new Font("Courier New", 6);
            payagainst = "PARADISE TRADING, CONT &  REAL ESTATE";
            amount = 3300;
            gs.DrawString(payagainst, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), float.Parse(txtpaX.Text), float.Parse(txtpaY.Text));
            flag = 1;
        }
    }
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: describe the symptom or give error message, so we know what is not working.

Comment: please look the comment i given for @Leo answer

Comment: Have you resolved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

What is supposed to happen after the string is printed over the image?

Do you need to save the image or pass it on or is the display in the `PictureBox` the only aim?

For the latter case this is the way to do it:

You place the drawing code only in the `Paint` event and call it, by invalidating the `PictureBox`, either whenever the `TextBoxes` have a change or when you leave them..:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawString(yourText, yourFont, yourBrush, 
                          float.Parse(textBox1.Text), float.Parse(textBox2.Text));
}

// this will show up only after leaving the textbox:
private void textBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}

// this will provide a live change:
private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}
```

Note that you should hook this code to **both** `TextBoxes`!

This code will persist the drawing but it will not change the actual Bitmap. Which I guess wouldn't make sense until you know exactly where the text should go..

If you want to change the actual Image you can do it like this:

```
private void stampButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image))
        G.DrawString(yourText, yourFont, yourBrush, 
                     float.Parse(textBox1.Text), float.Parse(textBox2.Text));
}
```

..and then maybe save it like this:

```
private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Image.Save("yourfilename", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.yourfileformat);
}
```